# Want to get just two object in json

Tags: php, json

I am trying to make a code verifier with the following code. I've looked at the answers in StackOverflow but couldn't get the right result.

The code is working fine but I want to echo just two value.

**validate.php** page code is here:

```
if(isset($apKey) && isset($code))   {
    $en     = new En();
    $Key       = $apKey;
    $Codes = $code;

if($Key == null || $Codes == null)  {
    echo json_encode(['data' => 'No Key or code found, Please try again']);
    exit;
}  
  $response = $en->validate($Key,$Codes);
  $result = json_decode($response);
  $elements = json_encode(['data' => $result]); 
  echo $elements;
  exit;
}
  echo json_encode(['data' => 'No Key or code found, Please try again']);
  exit;
```

Now I am trying to check this validate page results using this code:

```
$siteurl = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
    $arrContextOptions = array(
        "ssl" => array(
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false
        )
    );
    $file = file_get_contents('http://www.validates.com/validate.php?code=' . $check , false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
    $checks = json_decode($file, true);
    $elements = $checks['data']; 
    echo print_r($elements);
```

So the results something like this:

```
Array
   ( 
     [buyer] => abcd 
    )
```

So what I want to do. I want to echo just buyer and error message after this code: `$checks = json_decode($file, true);`

The error result is here:

```
{"data":{"error":404,"description":"No sale belonging to the current user found with that code"}}
```

Like for example:

```
if(buyer){echo 'true';}
if(error message){echo 'error';}
```

Comment: Instead of linking to your site and asking us to go there and check the console, put all information into the question itself (as text, not images). If not, this question will be useless for future visitors when those links change.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are right but that console code too long.

Comment: Probably not if you just include the relevant parts. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have edited my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can check with [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) if there is error. You can do something like this:

```
$checks = json_decode($file, true);
$data = $checks['data']; 
if (array_key_exists("error", $data))
    echo $data["description"];
else 
    echo $data["buyer"];
```